# Como graficar múltiples graficas con matplotlib desde terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

Como puedo graficar las dos graficas a la vez cuando compilo el programa?

Cuando lo compilo desde terminal `pyhton3 file.py` me arroja una grafica y después de cerrar me arroja la otra, no puedo hacer que me arroje las dos al mismo tiempo.

**Codigo**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pi=np.pi
f=30
dt=0.002

t=np.arange(-0.04,0.04,dt)
    
def onda(f,t):
    pift=(pi**2)*(f**2)*(t**2)
    f_t=(1.-2*pift)*np.exp(-pift)
    return f_t


t1=np.size(onda(f,t))
t2=t1*2
t3=np.linspace(1,t2,t1)

####Grafica 1 

plt.plot(t,onda(f,t))
plt.xlabel("Tiempo [ms]", size=12)
plt.ylabel("Amplitud", size=12)
plt.title("Ondicula",size=16)
plt.show()

####Grafica 2

plt.plot(t3,onda(f,t))
plt.xlabel("Tiempo [ms]", size=12)
plt.ylabel("Amplitud", size=12)
plt.title("Ondicula",size=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Quieres ver las 2 gráficas en una sola ventana o ver los 2 datos en la misma gráfica??

Comment: Quiero ver las 2 graficas al mismo tiempo en ventanas separadas.

Comment: Por cierto no llames 2 veces a `plt.show()` solo se hace 1 vez